# Do I still need the CAPTCHA in the frontend if I've already enabled ratelimiter in the backend?

Tags: web, captcha, rate-limiting

Is it redundant to have both? What's the purpose of having both?

Comment: Even if you have a rate limit, an automated process can send requests up to that limit. A captcha can prevent even that

Comment: CAPTCHA was used to prevent robots registering many accounts, the rate limiter is limit how much API they/human can call during a specify time. It's not redundant.